# equivalent of time for memory checking

Tags: unix, statistics

we can use `time` in a unix environment to see how long something took...

```
shell> time some_random_command
real    0m0.709s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.012s
```

is there an equivalent for recording memory usage of the process(es)?

in particular i'm interested in peak allocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the man page for time. You can specify a format string where it is possible to output memory information. For example:

```
>time -f"mem: %M" some_random_command
mem: NNNN
```

will output maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kilobytes.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, I needed to use the full path of time to skip the built-in and use the real one, _i.e._ `/usr/bin/time -f "mem: %M" ...`.  See [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86193/command-not-found-when-trying-to-set-a-format-for-the-time-command)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use ps? e.g. `ps v <pid>` will return memory information.

Comment: i was using ps but for short lived processes i was having trouble capturing the info